# Drupal strips my module name from the configure URL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a drupal Module, and in the .info file I have

```
configure = admin/config/services/bright
```

But if I mouse over the "configure" link in the admin console, it says just

```
admin/config/services
```

In my .module I have the following:

```
function bright_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['admin/config/services/bright'] = array(
    'title' => 'Bright',
    'description' => 'Configuration for Bright module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('bright_form'),
    'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

No matter what I change the configure setting to, it strips the last word off.

This is Drupal 7.

Note the overlay module is on, so the actual URL it generates is:

http://my-url/users/my-user-name#overlay=admin/config/services

My last comment this all worked in a vanilla install of Drupal 7, but now that I've taken it to my customer's build, with a lot more stuff enabled, it stopped working.

Things I've tried:

- clear/rebuilding the cache
- rebuilding the menus
- disabling and re-enabling the module.
- completely disabling the module, deleting it, and re-installing from a zip file

Comment: Rebuild your module registry or disable your module and enable it, I have checked it and its working. I can see the link completely

Comment: Clear the caches and have a check

Comment: I can't reproduce it, I enabled the overlay module and I can see the complete path menu.

Comment: Updating the description with these suggestions.

Comment: How do you rebuild the module registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with some help.

On the site itself, in the Drupal log:

```
/admin/reports/dblog
```

There were lots of errors like this:

[image]

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out in backup_migrate_source_db->_get_db_connection() (line 220 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/..../sites/all/modules/backup_migrate/includes/sources.db.inc).
```

Seems there was a second datasource configured in the settings.php / and this module

https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate

Wants to access the database to create the menu.

Removed it, and everything works fine.   Thanks!